# How export report to docx spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

the code below I use java to export a report in word with springboot, when the file is generated however it is empty how do I solve this?

**Java Code:**

```
   public static ByteArrayResource exportReportToDOCx(InputStream targetStream, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sto esportando il docx");
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(targetStream, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("/var/tmp/report.docx")));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
            exporter.exportReport();
            byte[] reportContent = outputStream.toByteArray();
            return new ByteArrayResource(reportContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exporting report to DOCx error: {}", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is “vuto”?

Comment: empty .........